# Hide a partial upon page load and then show partial on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3 and JQuery, I have a div that contains a rendered partial.  When I hide that div in my javascript using JQuery, it does not hide.  Why am I unable hide this?  I would simply like it to be hidden and then on a button click be shown.

My view

```
new.html.erb
  <div class="row carousel-div">

    <%= render "carousel", f: f %>

  </div
```

My javascript

```
carousel.js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".carousel-div").hide();
    });
```

I am not very comfortable with AJAX but that is the only answer I have found online.  Is there no way to do this without AJAX?  If AJAX is the only way, then out of curiosity why is the JQuery hide function made inactive and, of course, how would I institute the AJAX call?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby, but I am with jQuery and the ".carousel-dev" refers to a class and you class for the element is class="row carousel-dev".  Maybe that's why it's not working.

Comment: the selector is fine. the div is not closed properly..? i tested it in jsfiddle, and even with the wrong closed div the element is hidden. did you check your console? did you include jquery? http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/4779b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do the following and let me know. Usually div class is good practice for CSS only. 
Are you calling carousel.js inside new.html.erb?
modify the view like this:

```
new.html.erb
  <div id='something' class="row carousel-div">

    <%= render "carousel", f: f %>

  </div
```

javascript:

```
carousel.js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#something").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  I needed to use an id and not a class.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks I have upvoted your question, please upvote my answer too by clicking on up arrow button